# On Visual Studio 2017, how to close the software inside try/catch?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a software with C# on Visual studio 2017, and I want it to not initialize if the database is down, so I've tried the try/catch below, but still the software doesn't exit, I have two buttons to exit, and they work, but the exit on try-catch doesn't. I've tried a lot of things, placing the app.exit and close codes on many different places, calling from other functions, it just doesn't work.
This is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int errobd = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            string connectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=bd_cem";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Close();

            // at this point, the errobd++ works, so the if down there will be true
            errobd++;
            MessageBox.Show("Error message.");
            Application.Exit();
            Debug.WriteLine("ERRO = " + errobd);
        }
        if(errobd>0)
        {
            Sairsembanco();
        }

        LoadSalaNome();
        LoadADI();
    }
```

and after all this effort, the function LoadSalaNome() still tries to run, crashing the software due to the fact that the db is down.

Comment: Put a `return` after the `Application.Exit`.

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't be attempting to kill the application from the constructor of the main form.  Either (1) set a a flag and exit at a further point like the Load() or Shown() event, or (2) prevent the form from loading at all by doing this type of check in program.cs.

Comment: Thanks Idle_Mind, I will definitely take a look at the program.cs

Comment: Keneth K. I'm keeping the environment.exit, it worked nice. Sorry man :/, but if you give it a try, I would be happy to know if it works or if it doesn't.

Idle_Mind, i did used the try catch at program.cs, it works, even faster, thanks for the help !!

Comment: @KennethK. (just referencing)

Comment: @Idle_Mind (just referencing)

Comment: @viflaiban I don't understand the comment. I didn't suggest removing `Application.Exit`. I simply said to put a `return` after it.

Comment: @KennethK. but that implies in not using Environment.Exit, doesn't?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how I can state "Put a return __after__ the Application.Exit" any clearer.

Comment: @KennethK. you don't need to be rude, this do not need to became personal, for I've posted a technical question. It seems like you need a psychiatrist in order to resolve emotionally unfinished business of yours, please, go see a doctor. There should be a psychiatrist here at stack for I've seen people being oddly often pointlessly rude to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one also:

```
Environment.Exit(exitCode)
```

This terminates the process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code. This requires you to to have `SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode` permissions otherwise `SecurityException` error occurs. 
This is the call to use if you are running a console application.

Comment: OMG, you were fast, i thought this was going to take days to receive an answer, it worked!] thanks !